# Login ReturnUrl in ASP.NET WebForms causing JavaScript critical error when using IE11

Tags: javascript, asp.net, signalr, bundling-and-minification, returnurl

I am developing ASP.NET Web Forms application using Visual Studio 2012, which utilizes bundling and SignalR.

I put this in my web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" defaultUrl="~/Views/Portfolio" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users ="?" />
  <allow users = "*" />
</authorization>
```

When I hit F5 I get this kind of error:

```
JavaScript critical error at line 3, column 1 in http://localhost:6169/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=/bundles/WebFormsJs?v=AAyiAYwMfvmwjNSBfIMrBAqfU5exDukMVhrRuZ-PDU01&v=AAyiAYwMfvmwjNSBfIMrBAqfU5exDukMVhrRuZ-PDU01

SCRIPT1002: Syntax error
```

then followed by this:

```
JavaScript critical error at line 3, column 1 in http://localhost:6169/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=/signalr/hubs

SCRIPT1002: Syntax error
```

I am using IE11 and these kind of errors didn't happen when using Firefox or Chrome. Please help? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Typically you cannot bundle dynamically generated JavaScript such as /signalr/hubs.

If you want to bundle the /signalr/hubs script (aka the SignalR JS hub proxy), you need to [generate the script before deployment](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#manualproxy). This will give you a static JS file that you can bundle.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but i didnt bundle the SignalR script. apparently my method of denying anonymous users from all pages had backfired since they can't even access the login page (duh!). so i have removed the <authorization> part from web.config and have implemented another way of setting authorization rules. the reported errors were gone. i still dont know what had caused the error though..

Answer (score 1):

The solution put forward by Halter73 worked for me, initially.  I was getting similar errors in IE11 and specifically noticed the "ReturnUrl=/signalr/hubs" in the URL.  However, I found some regression issues with the static proxy (both a chat and a users online widget broke) and so I rolled it back to using the default dynamically generated proxy.

So after doing that, I was back to the same error and I returned here and re-read the OP's original post and his own reply very *carefully* and realized it might be an issue with the authorization settings in my web.config, of which there were none for signalr/hubs.  Like the OP I also deny auth from various areas of my site so I needed to explicitly allow access to signalr/hubs so I simply added this to fix my issue:

```
  <location path="signalr/hubs">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```